# Call to the component exceeded

Tags: angular

I am building an angular 4 app and implementing routing. My browser seems to make a call to the movie component umpteen times on the first page load. I can see the error message in the developer tools. It says maximum call exceeded. Not sure what the problem is. Here is the code

**screenshot**

[image]

**Home module**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { HomeComponent } from './home.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ],
  exports: [HomeComponent],
  declarations: [HomeComponent]
})
export class HomeModule { }
```

**Home Component**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

**Home.component.html**

```
<p>
  home works!
</p>
```

**Movie module**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import {MovieComponent} from './movie.component'

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ],
  exports: [MovieComponent],
  declarations: [MovieComponent]
})
export class MovieModule { }
```

**Movie component**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-movie',
  templateUrl: './movie.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./movie.component.css']
})
export class MovieComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

**appmodule**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import {FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import {HttpModule} from '@angular/http'

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { NavbarComponent } from './navbar/navbar.component';
import { TopbarComponent } from './topbar/topbar.component';
import { FooterbarComponent } from './footerbar/footerbar.component';
import { MRDBGlobalConstants } from './shared/mrdb.global.constants';
import {AppRoutingModule} from './app.routing';
import {HomeModule} from './home/home.module';
import {MovieModule} from './movie/movie.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    FooterbarComponent,
    TopbarComponent,
    NavbarComponent


  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HomeModule,
    MovieModule

  ],
  providers: [MRDBGlobalConstants],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

appcomponent

```
import { Component ,ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app';

constructor(public viewRef : ViewContainerRef) {

}

}
```

**app.routing**

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {Routes,RouterModule} from '@angular/router';
import {MovieComponent} from '../app/movie/movie.component';
import {HomeComponent}  from '../app/home/home.component';

export const appRoutes:Routes = [
  {path: '', component: HomeComponent},
  {path: 'movie', component : MovieComponent}

];

@NgModule({
imports:[RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes,{ useHash: true})],
exports:[RouterModule]

})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<section id="container">
    <top-bar>Loading top bar...</top-bar>
    <nav-bar>Loading navigation menu...</nav-bar>

    <footer-bar>Loading footer...</footer-bar>

        <app-movie></app-movie>
        <app-home></app-home>


    <router-outlet> </router-outlet>
</section>
```

**Developer Tools**
[image]
Screenshot 1

[image]

Screenshot 2

[image]

Comment: I can see the error message in the developer tools can you show us too it will be helpful in debugging

Comment: How about posting HTML templates too?

Comment: I have uploaded the templates. I am not sure what i am doing in approuting is correct

Comment: I have also uploaded the screenshot from developer tools

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you didn't have any routing for lazy loaded module.

I would suggest you to remove the Modules and then give it a try

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    FooterbarComponent,
    TopbarComponent,
    NavbarComponent,
    MovieComponent,
    HomeComponent   

  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpModule,
    AppRoutingModule// it should be something like this

  ],
  providers: [MRDBGlobalConstants],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

AppRoutingModule

```
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

const ROUTER_DATA: Routes = [
    { path:'home', component: yourroutes},
];

export const AppRoutingModule= RouterModule.forRoot(ROUTER_DATA);
```

Updated after Comment

```
<app-movie></app-movie>
    <app-home></app-home> // remove these lines
```

`<router-outlet></router-outlet>` this will fetch the component from the router and display and for home you are already redirecting it to the proper url

Comment: I tried your solution Rahul and the problem is the same for me. Instead of importing module , I imported the component. Not sure what is different in AppRoutingModule. So this solution doesnt work for me now

Comment: @Tom can you add a plunker for the same so that i can take a look at the same , or may be a Team Viewer

Comment: I have managed to fix the issue of endless call to movie component. The problem was that put the movie selector by mistake in movie.component.html file. I removed it and that fixed the issue

Comment: I would like to know that when i click on movie link , movie works  is displayed and if I click on root Home works is displayed. But in either case Home gets displayed always. So what I mean is that my default Home works is displayed and the second dom Home or Movie is displayed based on selection

Comment: you are using both the selector in the app component use only the routeroutlet rest everything is taken care bye the router updated ans